# Powershell : $host.version output different between script and shell

Tags: shell, powershell, output

Why the output of $host.version is different if we start it from a script called with ".\script.ps1" and if we execute the command un the shell ?

from shell :

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> $PSVersiontable

Name                           Value
---                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

from script :

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop>.\check.ps1
System.Collections.Hashtable

Key   : PSVersion
Value : 5.1.14409.1005
Name  : PSVersion

Key   : PSEdition
Value : Desktop
Name  : PSEdition

Key   : PSCompatibleVersions
Value : {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
Name  : PSCompatibleVersions
[...]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they're different hosts..  Console, ISE, etc. are all different hosts.

If you're referring to your PowerShell version, they aren't different, even in your own question.

Comment: Thanks TheIncorrigble1 :)

I suppose "script" are based on ISE host?
What's is the best practices if we want to test commands easily?

Comment: All hosts respond the same unless you have something in the `$Profile` that changes the environment @GJE

You can see your host by using the `Get-Host` command.